# Is it possible to get two output parameters from stored T-SQL procedure using Hibernate 4?

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, t-sql

I new in hibernate.
I need to call MS SQL 2008 procedure using Hibernate 4 and print results to console.

Proc:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[PRODUCT_CREATE](
        @ReturnValue INT output,
        @ProductID INT output,
        @PassID numeric(18,0),
        @Amount numeric(18,2))
  as
BEGIN
print 'PassID = ' + convert(varchar,  @PassID);
print 'Amount  = ' + convert(varchar, @Amount);
select @ReturnValue     = 999999,
       @ProductID       = 777777;
END;
```

Mapping:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping
    PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
          "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <sql-query name="PRODUCT_CREATE" callable="true">
        <return-scalar column = "retVal" type="int"/>
        <return-scalar column = "cardId" type="int"/>
        <![CDATA[{CALL PRODUCT_CREATE (:ReturnValue, 
                                            :ProductID, 
                                            :PassID, 
                                            :Amount 
                                            )}]]>
  </sql-query>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Main class:

```
package app;

import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.transform.Transformers;

public class App {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        App.createProduct();


        }



    public static BigInteger createProduct()
    {
        /**
         * Open session and begin database transaction for database operation.
         */
        SessionFactory sf =  HibernateUtil.createSessionFactory();
        Session session = sf.openSession();
        Query  qr = session.getNamedQuery("PRODUCT_CREATE");

        qr.setParameter("ReturnValue", 0); 
        qr.setParameter("ProductID", 0);
        qr.setParameter("PassID", new BigInteger("1000999"));
        qr.setParameter("Amount", new BigInteger("1000001"));

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
         /*The problem is here*/
        List<ProductModel> list = qr.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(ProductModel.class)).list(); 

        for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
            ProductModel prd = (ProductModel)list.get(i);
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(prd.getCardId()));
        }

        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();

        return null;

    }


}
```

Connection setup:

```
package app;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;

public class HibernateUtil {
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;


    /**
     * Create hibernate configuration.
     */
    Configuration c = new Configuration().configure("/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml");


    public static SessionFactory createSessionFactory() {

        try
        {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure();
        serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(
                configuration.getProperties()).build();
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        return sessionFactory;

        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
            System.out.print("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

}
```

Return object model:

```
package app;

public class ProductModel {

    private int retVal;
    private int cardId;


    public ProductModel(int retVal, int cardId) {
        super();
        this.retVal = retVal;
        this.cardId = cardId;
    }


    public int getRetVal() {
        return retVal;
    }
    public void setRetVal(int retVal) {
        this.retVal = retVal;
    }
    public int getCardId() {
        return cardId;
    }
    public void setCardId(int cardId) {
        this.cardId = cardId;
    }

}
```

Hibernate conf:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC 
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://.......</property>
    <property name="connection.username">user</property>
    <property name="connection.password">pass</property>
    <property name="connection.pool_size">10</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit">true</property>
    <!--<property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property> -->

    <mapping resource="app/PRODUCT_CREATE.hbm.xml"></mapping>

  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

POM:

```
<properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.3.8.Final</hibernate.version>
        <hibernate.jpa.version>1.0.0.Final</hibernate.jpa.version>
    </properties>

 <dependencies>

  <!--Hibernate-->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
                <version>${hibernate.jpa.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
            </dependency>


   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
        <version>4.0</version>
   </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Exception:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:950)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:921)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:355)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2554)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2540)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2370)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2365)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:353)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1873)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:311)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:141)
    at app.App.createProduct(App.java:46)
    at app.App.main(App.java:16)
```

How to fix exception and print out procedure's output parameters in console?

Comment: Is that the entire stacktrace, or only the top of it? Wild guess: your ProductModel class has no default no-arguments constructor, I would add one if I were you as that is a general rule for classes which are going to be automatically created and populated by frameworks. That's just something I spotted, I have no reason to believe nor any proof that is the actual cause of this particular issue.

Comment: This is full stacktrace without hibernate log. This is simplified example of my problem.

Comment: Yeah well sorry to say the first step to figuring out how to fix an exception is to know what causes it, what is presented here gives no chance of doing that. "Something" blows up when Hibernate processes the resultset. Might be wrong mappings, might be a bug in code you're not showing, no way to really know.

Comment: I specially prepared sample and provided all the code and text of the exception which I have.